# Non-linear equation with integrals

Tags: integration

I need to find an expression for $f(x)$ from the equation below:

$$ x f(x) + \int_0^x f(\alpha)d\alpha = \frac{f(x)}{1-\int_0^x f(\alpha)d\alpha} $$

How the heck do I solve this? Trial and error?

**Context**: what I'm doing is translating *pdfs* (which imply no order among the population) into an ordered group of elements. Think of a distribution of age for a population. I'm writing a function that can reproduce that distribution (think of a data generating process, DGP). For example, a uniform distribution $f(x)=1$ with support $[0,1]$ can be represented by $x(i)=i$, where $i$ belongs to $[0,1]$. (So, I'm ordering people in an increasing fashion according to their age. Of course, there are infinite orderings representing the same population but that is a trivial one).

Now, the exponential *pdf*, $f(x)=e^{-x}$, is consistent with the following ordering: $x(i)=-\ln(1-i)$. So what I'm doing now is the inverse process, this is, start from a given DGP and derive the *pdf* consistent with it. For the problem I posed above, the DGP is
$$x(i)=-\frac{\ln(1-i)}{i}$$

As you can see, it is very similar to the exponential one (on purpose) so I imagine the solution is a type of exponential. So, what I'm looking for is the *pdf* that this DGP generates. I imagine not all of these problems have closed form solution. I hope this one does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $g(x)=\int_0^x{f(\alpha)}$
The equation becomes something like $\frac{d(xg)}{dx}=-\frac{d Ln(1-g)}{dx}$  This gives you an equation for g which is unfortunately not solvable.

Comment: No solution then... but any possibility by implementing it in a software?

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: Solve for $\displaystyle \int_{0}^x f(\alpha)d\alpha$, and then taking derivative both sides to proceed.

Comment: You can't isolate it. You will need to use the chain rule and that integral will remain.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer. @luchonacho why would it remain? The derivative of the integral yields only f(x)

Comment: Once you take the derivative you will still have that integral around. It will never go away as it will always be multiplicating something else also depending on x and so you will end up with more and more derivatives of f(x) without eliminating the integral. You can try it if you want.